# Calling another activity from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I'm new to android and I have a problem with this code. I'm trying to get a JSON String and start another activity to display it as a ListView.
I'm not able to start the activity. It says that the ***The constructor Intent(RequestJsonString, Class) is undefined*** and ***The constructor Intent(RequestJsonString, Class) is undefined*** .

Here: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(RequestJsonString.this,DisplayResults.class);`
and Here:
`RequestJsonString.this.startActivity(intent);`

I have read many posts on this on stackoverflow and tried with `activity`, `context` and `this`. But still I'm not getting it right. I think I should be missing something. Any help is appreciated.

```
public class RequestJsonString extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
    // Code HTTP Get Request and get JSONObject
            return jsonObject;
}

protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObj){
    try {

        Intent intent = new Intent(RequestJsonString.this,DisplayResults.class);
        intent.putExtra("JSON_Object", jsonObj.toString());
        RequestJsonString.this.startActivity(intent);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v("Json_OutPut","Done");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are referring to asynctask class context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RequestJsonString.this,DisplayResults.class);
```

Use a Activity Context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,DisplayResults.class);
```

Check the link to know when to use getApplicationContext() and when to use Activity Context

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Edit:

Pass the Activity context to the asynctask constructor

```
 new RequestJsonString(ActivityName.this).execute(params..);
```

In your asynctask constructor

```
 Context c;
 public  RequestJsonString( Context context)
 {
        c= context;
 }
```

Then

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(c,DisplayResults.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The constructor Intent(RequestJsonString, Class<DisplayResults>) is undefined

Comment: pass the context to the asynctask constructor and use the same. check the edit above.

Comment: `public static void mygetJSONfromURL(String url){
     
     //initialize
     new RequestJsonString(MainActivity.this).execute(url);
     } `

Comment: This is in MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: remove the staticand try  public  void mygetJSONfromURL(String url){ //initialize new RequestJsonString(MainActivity.this).execute(url); }

Comment: Could you please explain why RequestJsonString.this wasn't working?

Comment: RequestJsonString.this  refers to your asynctask context. You should refer to the activity context since your class extends activity. If you need to startactivity from a non activity class, then you need the activity context and you can pass the same to the constructor of the non activity class. Check the link in the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be c.startActivity(intent)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28587/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-crocode)

Answer (score 2):

> To start the activity from AsyncTask.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivityName.this,DisplayResults.class);
```

or you can do same like below.

Declare the `context` instance variable and initialize it in `onCreate` method.

```
private Context context;
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   ............
   context = this;
   ........
}
```

Start the activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,DisplayResults.class);
intent.putExtra("JSON_Object", jsonObj.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context. getApplicationContext() is not tecommended

Comment: @Crocode it should be youractivityname.this. refer to the activity.